# unable to use inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I access I have two tables which I am combining using UNION ALL (This is working as expected). I would then like to add a new column which will be populated with different infomation depending on the value in colA. I have made a new table with this information and I am trying to use an inner join to assign the correct information. I am getting the following error message:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA, `Sheet1$`.colB, '' AS colG,

table1 INNER JOIN tabl2 ON table1.label1 = table2.label2 AS colF

FROM (

SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA, `Sheet1$`.colB
FROM `Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
UNION ALL
SELECT `Sheet2$`.colC, `Sheet2$`.colD
FROM `Sheet2$` `Sheet2$`
) t;
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: You miss a from before table1

Comment: Even after that you have so many mistakes

Comment: When I add that it says "The SELECT statement include a reserved word or an argumnet name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"

Comment: @kit - What are you trying to do ?

Comment: there are to many mistakes. throw it away and start from scratch... you may not end your select columnlist with a comma, you may not have a from in the mid of your from-clause, you may not have a join in your select, you should not have a crossjoin to your subselect...

Comment: MS Access does not support `UNION ALL` in derived tables.

Comment: The union all is working how I want. Not sure where to put the inner join though and get the information from table 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong.. Try this :

```
SELECT t.colA, t.colB, '' AS colG, s.<YourDesiredColumn>
FROM (
    SELECT `Sheet1$`.colA, `Sheet1$`.colB
    FROM `Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `Sheet2$`.colC, `Sheet2$`.colD
    FROM `Sheet2$` `Sheet2$`
    ) t
INNER JOIN table2 s ON t.colA = s.ColA
```

I didn't totally understand what do you need since the question was unclear. What is table1 and table2 ? How do they connect to the inner query? Anyway, adjust this.

Comment: table 1 should be the result of the union all and table 2 basically contains a key. It will compare the value in colA and then next to colA in table 2 there will be another value which will be displayed.

Comment: @kit Have a re look at the query, does it help now ?